# Can reports be generated using visualforce/apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, reports-api

I want to be able to generate reports through a visualforce section in account layout. Is it possible to generate a report through an apex class using a command button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, the answer of this question, is no. You can't develop or create Reports through the API.

However you can manage to visualize them by querying the system.

In creating reports, you should rely on the standard User Intereface, that Salesforce provides. Set the right permissions and user rights for your user profiles, and you will make sure that they can generate reports, related, only to the data that they can SEE.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of thought as much from a bit of research but just wanted a definite answer.